# Grouping using a column `cut` using `ordered_result = TRUE` does not list in ordered fashion

Tags: r, data.table

When we group a `data.table` by using breaks cut using `ordered_result = TRUE` does not list the cut breaks labels in increasing order (rather it seems to be in the order in which the breaks labels are found in the `data.table`, which is the same behaviour as with `ordered_result = FALSE`. Why does `data.table` not care about ordered factors ?

```
> aaa <- c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,7)
> aaa <- rev(aaa)
> d <- data.table(x = 1:length(aaa), val = aaa)
> # The following statement will not order the group by result using the ordered labels in increasing fashion.
> d[, sum(x), by = cut(aaa, 3, ordered_result = TRUE)]
         cut V1
1:  (5,7.01]  3
2:     (3,5] 22
3: (0.994,3] 41
> # Infact, the behavior is same as with ordered_result = FALSE
> d[, sum(x), by = cut(aaa, 3, ordered_result = FALSE)]
         cut V1
1:  (5,7.01]  3
2:     (3,5] 22
3: (0.994,3] 41
```

Comment: workaround: `setorder(d[, sum(x), by = .(cut(val, 3))], cut)`

Comment: That I know. But I do not understand the significance of the `ordered_result` and where it can possibly be used ? Everytime, one does grouping of this sorts, one needs to order it explicitly, despite using ordered_labels. What is the motivation behind not printing labels in increasing fashion, when they have an order.

Comment: Even if I do not use the ordered labels, ordering would suffice. Why is that ?

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to clarify what you want to know. My guess is simply that `data.table` doesn't care much about ordered factors - indeed I think they are rarely used in R.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between that ordering factors makes is largely limited to how the factors are treated in statistical models (it's alluded to in `?factor` but there's not a lot of detail).

The data.table extraction does not guarantee being sorted according to its `by` argument (whether or not it is an ordered factor). To achieve that, use the `keyby` argument:

```
d[, sum(x), keyby = cut(aaa, 3)]
#         cut V1
#1: (0.994,3] 41
#2:     (3,5] 22
#3:  (5,7.01]  3
```

In your example, the factor ordering works correctly, in that the `cut` column remains an ordered factor, compare the following:

```
str(d[, sum(x), by = cut(aaa, 3, ordered_result = TRUE)])
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ cut: Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "(0.994,3]"<"(3,5]"<..: 3 2 1
# $ V1 : int  3 22 41
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

str(d[, sum(x), by = cut(aaa, 3, ordered_result = FALSE)])
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ cut: Factor w/ 3 levels "(0.994,3]","(3,5]",..: 3 2 1
# $ V1 : int  3 22 41
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Note the change in the class of `cut` from `Ord.factor` to `Factor`.

Comment: Yes, the label orders could also simply be seen using the output of the two `cut` statements in isolation. But why does the grouping not list it properly. I wish to be able to use the ordered_labels in this simplistic fashion ? When would one use the ordered labels ? Even if I do not use the ordered labels, ordering would suffice. Why is that ?

Comment: @cryptickey Hopefully the edits have helped address your comments

Comment: `keyby` is the magic word

Comment: `?factor` says that Ordered factors differ from factors only in their class, but methods and the model-fitting functions treat the two classes quite differently. So, I think I am right in hoping that the ordered factors should work in the expected ways. But as you tell that `data.table` does not care about them, so I can change my expectation :)